# Understanding L2 Regularization Formula

Tags: notation, normed-spaces, machine-learning, regularization

I am currently following the [Machine Learning Crash Course on Tensorflow](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/regularization-for-simplicity/l2-regularization) and came across this formula:

$$L_2\text{ regularization term} = \|\boldsymbol w\|_2^2 = {w_1^2 + w_2^2 + \cdots + w_n^2}$$

I am having trouble understanding its notations.

I understand that the double bar, $\|\boldsymbol w\|$, denote some kind of *norm*, but what kind of norm is this? I am only familiar with the *Euclidean norm*.

Secondly, I don't understand why there's a subscript and superscript, $_2^2$, attached to the term. I'd think the subscript should be $n$ instead of $2$?

Comment: The superscript is just a square. The subscript means it is the $2$-norm, i.e., the Euclidean norm.

Comment: This is the square of Euclidean norm.  the subscript $2$ stands for the power of summands. so $\| v \|_2 = \sqrt{\sum^n_{i=1} v_i^2}$. And $\| v \|^2_2$ is the square of the sum.

Comment: $\| w \|_2$ is the $2$-norm of $w$, and $\|w\|_2^2$ is the square of the 2-norm of $w$. The superscript 2 is just an exponent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The genereal notation for $p$-norm for $p \in [1,+\infty)$  of vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is this:

$$
\| v \|_p = \sqrt[p]{\sum^n_{i=1} |v_i|^p}.
$$

It is easy to see that $\| v\|_2$ is indeed an Euclidean norm (let $p=2$ in the formula above) That is, Euclidean norm is 2-norm.

Then squaring produces

$$ \| v\|_2^2 = (\|v\|_2)^2 =\sum^n_{i=1} v_i^2 = v_1^2 +  v_2^2 \ldots  + v_n^2 $$

which is what you have specified.

Answer (score 1):

If you read [Boyd](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) in chapter six there is regularization and least squares problems. Regularization follows the following problem like this.

$$ \textrm{ minimize w.r.t }R_{+}^{2} (\| Ax -b\|,\|x \|) $$

this is called the bi-criterion problem which is a convex optimization problem.

Regularization has a general pattern which looks like this 
$$ \textrm{ minimize}  \| Ax -b\| +  \gamma \|x \| $$

Where we have a parameter $ \gamma \in (0,\infty) $  which is our regularization parameter. In the case of $\ell_{2}$ regularization we have

$$ \textrm{ minimize}  \| Ax -b\|_{2} +  \delta \|x \|_{2} $$

where our 2-norm  here $\|x \|_{2} = \left( \sum_{i=1}^{m} |x_{i} |^{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

The superscript simply means

$$ \| x \|_{2}^{2} =  \sum_{i=1}^{m} |x_{i} |^{2} $$

Comment: The only thing I don't get is why you changed $\gamma$ to $\delta$ in the next expression. I think it could confuse some people when they're really the same thing

Comment: it's just notation from Boyd. I think he changed it because $\gamma$ denotes a more general expression and $\delta$ denotes the expression for $\ell_{2}$

Comment: Yeah, but you specify this with the subscripts you've attached to the norms...but okay; you're just following the notation from Boyd. It's not important anyway. Another note: regularisation doesn't always follow this pattern. This is "Tikhonov type regularisation". However, there are also iterative methods (e.g. Landweber) which have quite a different look. But I concede this question relates to machine learning where Tikhonov type regularisation corresponds to ridge regression, LASSO, etc...I don't know if iterative methods are appropriate in that context.

Comment: I am not even sure what you're asking. I can't tell if that is a complete question.

Comment: I didn't ask any questions. I was making some comments.

Comment: I get the impression this is your specialty or something but also that you're really just talking at me, and not to me.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The comment isn't only for you but also for whoever else happens to read it. I suppose the main point, which was directed at you, was my issue with your claim that "regularisation has a general pattern which looks like..."

Comment: it is a basic form of regularisation, I am not claiming all regularization follows this approach. My answer literally says "Boyd saids blah blahl blah "